# Convert a date with timezone to GMT

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle11g, timezone

I have a date with time (eg 21-Mar-2014 08:00:00) with a time zone ("e.g. America/Denver") and I want to covert this date to GMT in; how could I do this?

I also want to know if Oracle takes DST? Will it handle it automatically? Are all timezones supported in the same way?

**NOTE** : The "from timezone" will change in every case; so, it's not always the America/Denver

Comment: Do you want to convert to GMT or UTC? Or, GMT during GMT time and BST (GMT + 1) in the summer?

Comment: GMT and UTC are the same ,its now refer to as UTC @Ben

Comment: i want to convert it to GMT @Ben

Comment: This is almost always better done in application code than in the database.  Can you provide some context?

Comment: Also, have you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004)?

Comment: There's an example of doing this [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699) that Matt linked to. Oracle should take DST into account automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of functions you can use:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Timestamp: ' || TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-21 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Timestamp with timezone: ' || FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-21 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'America/Denver') );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Timestamp at UTC: ' || FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-21 08:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'America/Denver') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' );
END;

Timestamp:               2014-03-21 08:00:00.000000000
Timestamp with timezone: 2014-03-21 08:00:00.000000000 -06:00
Timestamp at UTC:        2014-03-21 14:00:00.000000000 +00:00
```

Long timezone names like "America/Denver" consider DST. If you specify timezone generic like "-07:00" then DST is not considered.